# Google Translation Customized Button

Tags: javascript, google-translator-toolkit

I have required a simple button which can translate only one language like only french when i click on it . please help if anyone have an idea

Comment: Actually, this is not a question... Also, you are not clear with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://translate.google.com/translate?tl=fr&u=http://google.com">translate to french</a>
```

do not forget to replace variable 'u' with your page url

Comment: Thank you it is working but Don't want to open in google frame